# How to make image to be inserted using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to insert a form that has an image field. I'm able to get my text field but I'm trying to get the image. When I use console.log my image is undefined.

My laravel blade

```
<!-- This gets the admin template from app/modules/templates/views -->
@extends('templates::layouts.admin')
<!-- This inserts the content below into the template -->
@section('content')
{{ Html::script('js/admin/menu.js') }}
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'admin.menus.store', 'class' => 'add-form', 'files' => true)) }}
    <div class="form">
        <div class="title_input">
            <div>
                {{ Form::label('title', 'Title') }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ Form::text('title','', array('id' => 'title', "class" => "form-control")) }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone" name="mainFileUploader">
            <div class="fallback">
                <input class="test_image" name="file" type="file" multiple />
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
                url: "{{ asset("uploads/upload.php?target=menu_images") }}",
            };
        </script>

        <div class="submit_button">
            <div>
                {{ Form::submit('Submit', array("class" => "btn btn-info submit", "role" => "button")) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

@stop

My js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".add-form").submit(function(e){

    var formData = {
        title : $('#title').val(),
        image : $('.test_image').val(),
    }

    console.log(formData);
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

and in my firebug I have this

> Object {title="test, image=undefined}

Comment: I doubt you have element with `test_image` class on your `DOM`

Comment: Please add your HTML to the question. If you do have an `img` element, then they do not have a `value` attribute which is why you see `undefined` in the console.

Comment: Maybe you mean `image : $('.test_image').attr('src'),`?!

Comment: Please show your HTML

Comment: I've updated my question to include the form

Answer (score 0):

img-tag normally has no attribute value: [Check This](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp)

Try this:
$('.test_image').attr('value');

Answer (score 0):

The `img`-element does not have a `value` attribute. Use `src` instead.

```
var formData = {
    title : $('#title').val(),
    image : $('.test_image').attr('src'),
}
```

Watch out though, this only returns the `src` of the first `test_image` it encounters since you're referring to a class - using an **id** for your image might be better.

```
$('#test_image').attr('src')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code for submitting form with image : -

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(evt)
{
    evt.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "<Your POST URl>",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: new FormData(this),
        success: function (data, status) {
          // code here
        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err){
          // error handling code
        }
    });        

});
```